# Mysql rename JPG to jpg

Tags: mysql

I'm switching from a windows server to a linux server and case sensitivity is a bit of a problem in the database. For most fields I've just been able to use the following command:

```
UPDATE images_T SET image_path = LOWER(image_path)
```

However for one of the fields I need to change just the JPG part to jpg and keep all other capitalization. Eg. \images\T\12435.JPG I want to change to \images\T\12435.jpg so I want to keep the capital T. I've tried using the RIGHT function to do this but haven't had much luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE images_T SET image_path = REPLACE(image_path, '.JPG', '.jpg')
```

With `LEFT+Right` (works with any extension):

```
UPDATE images_T SET image_path = CONCAT(
                                   LEFT(image_path, length(image_path - 3))
                                 , lower(RIGHT(image_path, 3))
                                 )
```

Comment: thanks, works like a charm... I knew it would be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
UPDATE images_T set image_path = replace(image_path,'.JPG','.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)